# Does "persistence" slow down boot and shutdown on a USB linux?

Tags: live-usb

Essentially, my question is: how does casper-rw (IIRC) work?
Every time it boots, it copies the entire file? Every time it shuts down, it recreates it?

Also does its size affect the speed?

RTFM links on casper-rw/persistence appreciated.

Comment: casper-rw isn't the only implementation of persistence.

Comment: Any other examples?